# NSLog executes immediately rather than at end of loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have the following code inside of an IBAction. I'd like to measure the exact amount of time it takes AVSpeechSynthesizer to run through a list of directions. However, executionTime gets logged immediately rather than at the end of the loop (returning less than a second rather than the 10-15 seconds I expected). What did I do wrong?

```
NSDate *methodStart = [NSDate date];

for (NSString* direction in directions) {

    AVSpeechUtterance *aDirection = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:direction];
    aDirection.rate = .3;
    [self.synthesizer speakUtterance:aDirection];
}

NSDate *methodFinish = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval executionTime = [methodFinish timeIntervalSinceDate:methodStart];
NSLog(@"executionTime = %f", executionTime);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the `speakUtterance` call is asynchronous.
Make your class implement the AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate protocol and set it as the AVSpeechSynthesizer's delegate, and finally implement the `speechSynthesizer:didFinishSpeechUtterance:` message.

Comment: This delegate will be called once for each `AVSpeechUtterance`, so you will also have to count the calls to only print the time at the end or you can have multiple log entries and just care about the last one.

Comment: Beginning iOS programmer so still working on understanding how to use delegates, but this gives me a direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I don't know for a fact, but I would assume that `speakUtterance` is not a blocking call.  Meaning what you want it to do is added to a queue of things that happen in a background thread, then the code returns to you immediately allowing you to move on with other things in your code without having that thread wait for the utterance to complete..

I don't know how you would know how long it takes for the OS to create and read out the audio that it creates.

Edit:  But apparently Merlevede does...